# How can I order a query by the domains of email addresses?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, concatenation

I have not used concatenation in SQL much and don't know how I would do this.

Say I have an Email column containing a few email addresses (varchar).
Then I  have another column for LastLogin (datetime).

```
john@gmail.com
Frank@yahoo.com
Donny@apple.com
```

How would a query look for sorting firstly by the lastLogin date, and then by the domain name of  the emails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `charindex()` and `substring()`:

```
order by lastLogin,
         substring(email, charindex('@', email) + 1, len(email))
```

If you want the *date* component of the login:

```
order by cast(lastLogin as date),
         substring(email, charindex('@', email) + 1, len(email))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using MySQL, the following query should work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable ORDER BY lastLogin, SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', -1);
```

You provide to SUBSTRING_INDEX the name of the column, your delimiter and the number of occurrences of the delimiter as -1, in order to get everything on the left hand side after the delimiter.

Comment: …but a handy assumption for anyone searching for a MySQL solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may help

```
select * from table order by  `lastLogin date`,reverse(email);
```